# Calling other user In procedure Body of one User

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle9i

I am using following Query in Oracle 11g Procedures

```
Open cur_Test FOR
   '''Select * from '|| DBUSER ||'.table_name''';
```

Its raising an error 'Invalid SQL Statement.'

Can we call other user's table in  any user's package or procedure?

Comment: Just remove the inner `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
Open cur_Test FOR
   'Select * from '|| DBUSER ||'.table_name';
```

Of course you need to have `select` grants on that table...

Comment: Thanx for ur answer, I made this change, now error is in its next step  "Can not find table". But that table is present in defined user name.

Comment: Make sure that you have `SELECT` permissions on that table

Comment: Thanx A.B.Cade That was the exact issue. Fixed it. Thanx evryone.